Remove Namespace Prefix From ObjectID In Laravel Scout
I've got a Laravel scout project with Algolia. On my index, my record's objectId is being prefixed by the namespace. Here's an example "objectID": "App\\Models\\Path::6bc4105c-8eb2-4eda-8a29-201a04687725". I've got my getScoutKey() set to return $this->uuid.
Any ideas how I can remove the namespace prefix?

https://github.com/algolia/scout-extended/blob/master/src/Searchable/ObjectIdEncrypter.php override class?

Thanks for the reply! I did look into doing that but the class is called statically and not via the container so I can't bind a custom instance unfortunately. I found others with this same problem. Ended up going with separate indices for different namespaces.
